# Apache cordova setting in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I want to make a blank App (Apache cordova) in Visual Studio, but it is showing the following errors in the ActivityLog.xml

> SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]
>
> End package load [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]

Comment: if you only give the most basic error description, all we can do is search for them with google, and this you can do yourself. so please give more information (for example, your code). also tell us what else you see going wrong, and what you already tried to solve it.

Comment: hey Abinash! general rule here is to not write thank you comments, but instead up-vote comments and useful answers, and accept answers that solved the problem for you as you expected it. the reason for not writing thank you comments, is that other people that will read the question, answer and comments will not have to read things that do not matter to them (so you do not waste their time). it might seem unnatural at first, but it makes sense here.
if you solved the problem yourself in an other way then the given answer(s), please post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try first closing Visual Studio, then clear or rename your ComponentModelCache folder in the path %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 (14.0 for Visual Studio 2015) and restart Visual Studio. Then, create a Blank App (Apache Cordova) project again.